# PHP: Comparing an array, getting largest value and updating

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that's submitted from a menu and I have to take the largest value of a subcategory and only use the highest price. The updates can occur multiple times as the user adds more items.

`User Scenario`: User clicks on an ingredient, then another, then another. During each addition, prices are updated dynamically.

One of the subcategories is `salad greens` or `ingredienttype_id = 1`.

Current Code:

```
  $prices = $db->get_ingredient_prices($list);
  $free_items = $db->get_free_ingredient_types($item);

    foreach($prices as $price){
      if(array_key_exists($price['ingredienttype_id'], $free_items)){
        $qtyA = $free_items[$price['ingredienttype_id']];
        $qtyB = $customizations[$price['id']];

        if($qtyA == 0){
          $qtyC = $qtyB;
        } elseif($qtyA > $qtyB){
          $free_items[$price['ingredienttype_id']] = $qtyA - $qtyB;
          $qtyC = 0;
        } elseif($qtyA < $qtyB){
          $free_items[$price['ingredienttype_id']] = 0;
          $qtyC = $qtyB - $qtyA;
        } else {
          $free_items[$price['ingredienttype_id']] = 0;
          $qtyC = 0;
        }

      } else {
        $qtyC = $customizations[$price['id']];
      }

      if ($qty > -1) {
        $customizations_total = $customizations_total + ($price['price'] * $qtyC);
      } else {
        $customizations_total = $customizations_total + $price['price'];
      }
    }

    return number_format($customizations_total,2);
```

Now I have to create my loop within this sample code, somehow.

Here is a sample output from a foreach loop when attempting to get the proper category:

```
$list = [4, 6, 8, 114, 98];
$prices = $db->get_ingredient_prices($list);

  foreach ($prices as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['ingredienttype_id'] == '1') { $greens[] = $v; }
  }
```

Sample Output:

```
array (size=6) [prices]
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Spinach' (length=7)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'price' => string '0.69' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d40' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '55' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Kale' (length=4)
      'description' => string 'Local' (length=5)
      'price' => string '0' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001d48' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '71' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Bleu Cheese' (length=11)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'price' => string '0.69' (length=4)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001d42' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '160' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '98' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Asian Sesame' (length=12)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'price' => string '0.69' (length=4)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d3d' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '125' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '114' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Arugula ' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'Local' (length=5)
      'price' => string '0.99' (length=4)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d24' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '35' (length=2)

array (size=3) [greens]
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Spinach' (length=7)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'price' => string '0.69' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d40' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '55' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Kale' (length=4)
      'description' => string 'Local' (length=5)
      'price' => string '0' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001d48' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '71' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '114' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Arugula ' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'Local' (length=5)
      'price' => string '0.99' (length=4)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d24' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '35' (length=2)
```

From the Greens, I have to ONLY record Arugula's price, since it's the highest. This check has to be performed for each new addition, or even possible removal of Arugula.

I'm thinking that I'm going to be using multiple foreach loops, after getting the `$prices` array to

1. Get the `$greens` array
2. Get the max from the prices and record the item ID
3. Re-iterate over the original `$prices` array and set prices of ingredients, that match `ingredienttype_id == 1`, to 0 while leaving the output of max.

So I'm sort of stuck with 3 `foreach` loops to get my desired outcome. Is there a better way or is this the only way to go?

Comment: how are you maintaining the state (list of ingredients) on the server between adding and removing ingredients?

Comment: Items that are added are stored in the `$_SESSION['items']` variable. The `return` statement will "push" the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you track a user's selected ingredients on the database, which will allow you to easily query the total price.

When a user adds/removes an ingredient, you can update a join table consisting of the following columns:

```
selected_ingredients
(user_id, ingredient_id)
```

Then you can calculate the maximum price per ingredient type:

```
select max(price), ingredienttype_id
from ingredients i
join selected_ingredients si on si.ingredient_id = i.id
where si.user_id = ?
group by i.ingredienttype_id
```

Or the total as

```
select sum(price) from (
    select max(price) price, ingredienttype_id
    from ingredients i
    join selected_ingredients si on si.ingredient_id = i.id
    where si.user_id = ?
    group by i.ingredienttype_id
) t1
```

If you're already tracking the selected products in a session, then you don't need to record the selections in a join table and could use the following query, instead:

```
select sum(price) from (
    select max(price) price, ingredienttype_id
    from ingredients     
    where id in (?)
    group by ingredienttype_id
) t1
```

Comment: A standard transaction, from a user, can add 3-5 ingredients per session. If 20-30 users are concurrent, wouldn't the DB approach create a damper? From my understanding, you're suggesting that adding items should be separate from calculating the price, am I correct?

Comment: @Bardworx yes, they would be separate queries. it's difficult to tell whether using a db would be slower than using php. (with the right indexes) a db is generally much faster than php at solving this type of problem but if you have multiple web servers and a single db, using servers may be more scalable.

Comment: @Bardworx on second thought, you don't need to write the customer's selection to the db if you're already managing that in the session. you could replace the join by `where i.id in (selected product ids here)`

Answer (score 0):

I did another solution in clean PHP, in case this helps someone.

Step 1: After submit, I make sure the quantity of the item is greater then 1. Submitting empty values for IDs won't work.

Then:

```
// Get all the greens with built in PHP function - very handy.
      $greens = array_filter($prices, function($v) { return $v['ingredienttype_id'] === '1'; });

      // Get the most expensive green and save it
      if ( count($greens) > 1 ) {

        $max_greens = array_reduce($greens, function ($a, $b) {
          return @$a['price'] > $b['price'] ? $a : $b;
        });

        foreach ($prices as $k => $v) {
          if ($v['ingredienttype_id'] === '1' && $v['id'] !== $max_greens['id']) {
            $prices[$k]['price'] = '0';
          }
        }
      }
```

Was a bit of a pain but it worked well.